# I want to get values to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing a e-commerce site of pizza shop. i Have a database from where i am getting data about the pizza.I show data in table from database table.

Here is the table:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, price, qty FROM appetisers";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       // output data of each row
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                $quantity = $row["qty"]; 
                if ($quantity == '' || $quantity == '0') {
                   $quantity = '1';
                }  
          ?>
          <tr class="eachrow">
             <td><?php echo $row["name"] ?></td>
             <td class="price-amount">£ <?php echo $row["price"] ?></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="amount-type" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>"/></td>
             <td><a href="" class="add-cart" onclick="add_to_cart('<?php echo $row["name"] ?>', '<?php echo $row["price"] ?>')">Add to cart</a></td>
          </tr>
         <?php }
               }
       ?>
```

i want the item-name,item-price and item-quantity to a javascript fite from where i can send to a php file for processing through ajax.My javascript file is:

```
$(function(){

   $('.add-cart').click(function(e){
   var val = $(e.target).closest('.eachrow').find('[ name="amount"]').val();


   e.preventDefault();
})


   function add_to_cart(product_name,product_price){

    var dataString = "item_name=" + product_name + "&item_price=" + product_price + "&item_quantity=" + val + "&page=add_to_cart";


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/processor/processor.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }

    })
}
```

});

and my php file is :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['item_name']) && !empty($_POST['item_name']) && isset($_POST['item_price']) && !empty($_POST['item_price']) && isset($_POST['item_quantity']) && !empty($_POST['item_quantity'])){

    echo product_name;

}
```

?>

But is shows "ReferenceError: add_to_cart is not defined" in console

Comment: are you sure you put the `add_to_cart` function after the php code that calls it?

Comment: Your `<script>` element is missing or wrong.

Comment: Is that the entire JS file? Or is that code run from within `$(document).ready()` or some other handler - if so, `add_to_cart()` will be local to the block, invisible to the outside world.

Comment: Where do you call `add_to_cart()` in your javascript code?

Comment: $(document).ready() is okay .

Comment: @A.Wolff this is a seperate js file not inline.

Comment: @A.Wolff can i send u my entire file?

Comment: @hasan No, please... Do you include this file? If yes, how? Any error in network tab?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include your javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pathToJs.js"></script>
```

Comment: This could be the answer if the op has not included his file or his page does not have any script block containing the function.